# Google Keep for iOS - Is there a setting to play a sound with reminder?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, reminders, google

I'm trying out [Google Keep](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-keep-your-thoughts/id1029207872?mt=8) for iOS 9 on an iPhone 5. I've given the app permission to produce banners, sounds and alerts in the Notification Center. Timed reminders from Google Keep do show as banners, but no sound or vibration is produced. For me, alerts without sound or vibration are easy to miss. The silence switch is OFF for this phone (sound is on).

Has anyone found a combination of settings, or some strategy to cause sound and/or vibration with banners raised by Google Keep for iOS?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow up - others have raised this issue on [Google Docs Help Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/fa6a88cFkpU;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Akeep$20ios$20app) - I've submitted a feedback request related to this issue myself also. If you're having a similar problem - let's submit some feedback requests and get this enhancement implemented!

Answer (score 1):

[Google Keep for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-keep-your-thoughts/id1029207872?mt=8) was updated today 11/5/2015, after some quick tests the issue appears resolved. Sound/Vibrate on reminders is working in my case.

Thanks to all who read or posted on SO or elsewhere regarding this question.

Also, thanks go out to Google. Well played.